# How to match horizontal ellipse (…) in php

Tags: php, regex, php-5.3

I want to replace the horizontal ellipse (…) with three period (...)in a given string.
Till now I have tried are:

`str_replace('…','...', $text);`
`str_replace('&#8230;', '...', $text);`
`str_replace('&hellips', '...', $text);`

But not able to get the desired output. Can you please suggest some method for it.

**EDIT:**
One more problem I am facing related to this is when I paste the ~…~u character in my editor (I am using Editplus). the ... are converted into a rectangle. (see screenshot). 
[image]

Thanks

Comment: The first will work, but you need to instruct your editor that the file is UTF-8. This will also fix the "edit" problem.

Comment: @Jon My editor encoding is already UTF-8

Comment: Your first method [should work fine](http://3v4l.org/Q4p51). I'd say that you are simply guessing what that char is from a visual inspection of the HTML-rendered view. Additionally, I'm curious about why you think you need to remove that char.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario for the reason of not working see my edit part of question. The reason I want to remove is that when I am processing the text I want to exempt puncutation character from it like period, comma and this ellipsis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use preg_replace with the /u modifier (the string is treated as an unicode string):

```
$result = preg_replace('~…~u', '...', $string);
```

Comment: @jimy: try to type yourself the character

Comment: How can I do that? which key (or combination) on keyword will give that ?

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
str_replace('&#8230;', '...', htmlentities($text));
```

Comment: No luck... the ellipsis is converted into some wired characters when htmlentities is applied

Comment: This worked for me:
`str_replace('&amp;hellip;', '', htmlentities($str));`

Comment: Works, but encodes all html in the string too, for example if you use this for WordPress (more…) link. `str_replace( '&hellip;', '', $str);` works to just replace the hellip sign.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
str_replace( '&hellip;', '', $str);
```